# Injecting serverside data when using ISpaBuilder.UseReactDevelopmentServer

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc-5

When using ASP.NET (Core, .NET 5) MVC's `IApplicationBuilder.UseSpa` / `ISpaBuilder.UseReactDevelopmentServer` (in development), is there a way to postprocess the index HTML before it's sent to the browser? I need to inject a script tag holding data about the currently auth'd user to be consumed by the React app.

I want to avoid having to do an extra call from inside my React app just to get the currently logged on user at startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom middleware to do that. Assuming you're on .net core 3.1, the middleware would look something along these lines:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestReactDevServer.Middleware
{
    public class ScriptInjectorMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public ScriptInjectorMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            //Save pointer to the original response body stream
            var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

            //Create new memory stream
            using (var responseBody = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //...and use it for subsequent requests so we can peek the contents
                context.Response.Body = responseBody;

                //Continue down the Middleware pipeline, eventually returning to this class
                await _next(context);

                //inspect response, inject script
                await InjectScript(responseBody, "window.myUser='123';");

                //copy the contents of the new memory stream to the original place
                await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
            }
        }

        private async Task<Stream> InjectScript(Stream input, string script) 
        {
            input.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var decompressed = new MemoryStream();
            using (var tmp = new GZipStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
            {
                tmp.CopyTo(decompressed);
            }

            var html = await decompressed.StreamToString();
            var modifiedHtml = Regex.Replace(html, "</body>[\\n\\r]+</html>", $"<script type=\"text/javascript\">{script}</script></body></html>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline); // any way to locate closing tags will work here, you probably can be more efficient

            input.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            using (var modifiedHtmlStream = modifiedHtml.ToStream())
            using (var tmp = new GZipStream(input, CompressionMode.Compress, true)) // might be optional
            {
                modifiedHtmlStream.CopyTo(tmp);
            }

            return input;
        }
    }

    public static class ScriptInjectorMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseScriptInjectorMiddleware(
            this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<ScriptInjectorMiddleware>();
        }
    }

    public static class StreamExtensions {
        public static async Task<string> StreamToString(this Stream stream) {
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return await new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEndAsync();
        }
        public static Stream ToStream(this string str)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(str);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return stream;
        }
    }
}
```

a couple of things to point out:

1. Testing this with Chrome, I ended up having to decompress the proxied response and compress it back after modification - I think compression step might be optional.
2. Depending on your user agent you might need to handle more compression cases (see more examples on [Github](https://github.com/alexanderkozlenko/aspnetcore-request-decompression))
3. You will need to inject this middleware before your call to `.UseSpa()` in `Startup.cs`: adding `app.UseUserInjectorMiddleware();` should pick up the included extension method

I suspect this example is far from being complete, especially in terms of handling different encodings and content types - I am hoping you'd be able to adapt the idea to your use case.

Comment: This was going to be my backup strategy - just brute force change the response. Your example code provides a few interesting pointers for that, thanks.

I'm however still hoping to find something that is actually more closely supported by the SPA functionality, to avoid messing with the response on requests that weren't handled by the SPA handler to begin with.